# Replace double quotes that are not escaped using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to remove all double quotes except if they are escaped!

My example is as following:

```
 The quick brown fox "jumps", over  the 'lazy \"dog\"'
```

I want to reach the following result:

```
 The quick brown fox jumps, over  the 'lazy \"dog\"'
```

So fare i have the following command, but it does not work.

```
sed -i '/^\/\"/! s/"//g' test.sql
```

How can i write a sed commands that achieves my goal?

Regards Kim

Comment: How is your escaping defined? Is `\\"` a backslash followed by an escaped quote, or an escaped backslash followed by an unescaped quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be an option:

```
$ sed -r 's#([^\])"#\1#g' a
The quick brown fox jumps, over  the 'lazy \"dog\"'
```

From the basic `sed 's#something#change#g'`, it looks for any `something different than \` + `"` and deletes it. It also catches that character (`(something)`) and prints it back (`\1`).

For edge cases, as [described by jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561419/replace-double-quotes-that-are-not-escaped-using-sed/19561461?noredirect=1#comment29028387_19561461):

> A couple corner cases, -e 's/""*/"/g' before the main one to handle
>   consecutive quotes and -e s/^"//` to handle initial quotes.

```
$ cat a
The quick brown fox "jumps", over  the 'lazy \"dog\"'
"The quick brown fox "jumps", over  the 'lazy \"dog\"'""
$ sed -re 's/""*/"/g' -e 's/^"//' -e 's#([^\])"#\1#g' a
The quick brown fox jumps, over  the 'lazy \"dog\"'
The quick brown fox jumps, over  the 'lazy \"dog\"'
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid losing the space between fox and jumps? The s on jumps is also removed.

Comment: A couple corner cases, `-e 's/""*/"/g' before the main one to handle consecutive quotes and `-e s/^"//` to handle initial quotes.

Comment: Great, @jthill, just updated to show your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: need the duplicate-reduction first, did the fix

Comment: When i execute the commands i get the following error.
    $ sed -re -e 's/""*/"/g' -e 's/^"//' -e 's#([^\])"#\1#g' test2.sql
    sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `-'

Comment: There was a `-e` too much, I just removed it from my answer, @KimA.Jakobsen

Comment: This solution fails when there are `"` later in the line, like `The quick brown fox "jumps", over  the 'lazy \"dog\"' here are some "more data"` gives `The quick brown fox jumps, over  the 'lazy \"dog\"' here are some more data` Look at the `more data`

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` version (not the best way to do it)

```
awk '{gsub(/\\\"/,"_#_");gsub(/\"/,x);gsub(/_#_/,"\\\"")}1'
The quick brown fox jumps, over  the 'lazy \"dog\"'
```

Here it replace the `\"` to `_#_` (this needs to be some unique)
Then it remove the single `"` and change back to `\"`

---

A less portable gnu `awk version`

```
awk '{print gensub(/([^\\])\"/, "\\1", "g")}'
The quick brown fox jumps, over  the 'lazy \"dog\"'
```

---

A good `awk` version (portable):

```
awk '{gsub(/[^\\]"/,"&_");gsub(/"_/,x)}1'
```

---

Best `awk` version so far (portable):

```
awk '{ORS=(/\\$/?RS:x)}1' RS=\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a temporary substitution (here char # ) on posix sed

```
sed 's/#/#a/g;s/\\"/#b/g;s/"//g;s/#b/\\"/g;s/#a/#/g' File.ext
```